# Increase size of root in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I have been using Ubuntu 20.04 with a root memory of 10Gb. Lately the system refuses to install or update packages saying "Not enough free space". I want to increase the size of the root memory by taking space from some other partition but do not want to do so by reinstalling Ubuntu.
This is how my Gparted looks.

[Gparted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vC1Zo.png)

I have seen other answers to similar questions too but most of them are outdated or not in sync with the options that my system gives.
How can I fix this, I would like to increase the root to 20Gb now.

Comment: Do you have an encrypted partition? Probably, because you have a separate /boot. It could be your /boot that is full. Remove old kernels. That said, 10 GB for / is little. However, you will need some heavier partition editing to take some space from /home and add to /: partitions need to be moved, which may make this a lengthy process with a certain risk of failure.

Comment: @vanadium Do you consider reinstalling (this time with desired space) would be the correct approach now?

Comment: It doesn’t look like /boot is full. In fact it seems to be rather large at over 9GB. I’d have thought you could move about 8GB from /boot to / with GParted which might be enough for you. There could be issues doing this so backup your data first. You will need to boot a live usb/cd to do this so that the partitions you are working on are not mounted. Might be worth trying first and reinstall if it goes wrong.

Comment: You can reduce boot, then move it, then expand root. Moving a partition is slow and may go wrong, but in this case, it will be a small partition. Hit "Apply" (the green checkmark) after every step. Make sure your backup is up to date in case it goes wrong.